# inserting image on header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a logo in my header. It has a div with class bannerPicture where I have specified the location of logo:

```
.bannerPicture
    {
     width: 213px;
     height:128px;
     background: url(logo_uhhipl.gif) repeat 0px 3px;
    }
```

and my html is as follows:

```
<header>
    <div id="showlogo" class="bannerPicture">
    </div>
</header>
```

My problem is, the logo appears behind the text if i add any text within the div "showlogo" and it does not display if i leave it blank like above. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Is it because I do not have  inside div?

Comment: try url("../logo_uhhipl.gif") try to verify where is your image...

Comment: "the logo appears behind the text"...isn't that where backgrounds belong?

Comment: but i did not want any text on top of my logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is in the CSS, it appears as a background image. Also, since there is no specified width or height for the element, the background won't show. It seems to me what you are aiming to do is actually declare the image in the HTML, **not** the CSS.

Comment: Okay, I am very new to html & css so these are very basic questions for you all. I added an <img src="logo.gif" /> inside the showlogo div and it worked. But is that the correct way?

Comment: If you are looking to add a clickable logo, than that is definitely what you want to do. Think of CSS as the "look" of the page, and the HTML as the "content". Something like a logo is content, or a picture associated with a story or blog entry. That and since most logos will lead you back by clicking on them, you need to have it as an HTML element in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior for background images. That's where the name comes from. If you want to add a logo, just use an "img" tag instead. Or if you prefer using CSS, you can use an "a" tag with a background image specified - because logos are usually clickable and return you to the home page.